# How to go around websites that block or flag to ip addresses

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Ive noticed of late a good number of websites block tor using either google capture or its other popular compatriot. Has anyone figured out how to go around this while still using tor. With the latter, you click a few images of busses traffic signs or roads and you are in but google is brutal and wont allow you in

Is tor making any progress to rectify this e.g. adding ne ip addresses on a minute by minute basis?

Answer (score 1):

When a good website blocks Tor, I try to fix it using a "web proxy", like:

- https://whoer.net/webproxy
- https://www.kproxy.com/
- https://proxy.toolur.com/
- https://hidester.com/proxy/

It works if the website doesn't block all proxies, only Tor. Some websites also blocks "web proxies", and I haven't found a solution for these ones yet (you can try to solve this by searching for a new "web proxy" service in [DuckDuckGo](https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/) that doesn't exists in website's firewall yet).